# Websockets in Python for instance exec command in LXD

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, lxd

I trying execute a command in a instance by LXD API [/1.0/instances/{name}/exec](https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/api/#/instances/instance_exec_post) in interactive mode, and getting two sockets - *bi-direction* and *control* as described in the documentation:

```
In interactive mode, a single bi-directional websocket is used for stdin and stdout/stderr.

An additional "control" socket is always added on top which can be used for out of band communication with LXD.
This allows sending signals and window sizing information through.
```

Below it my Python code. Copy source code to new a file and save it. Then replace value of `instance_name` to your an instance name and run the code:

```py
import os
from requests import Session, Response
import requests_unixsocket
from urllib import parse
from shlex import shlex


unix_socket = '/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket'
instance_name = 'pgsql'


# ------------------------------------ Certs default paths ---------------
lxc_conf_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.config/lxc/')
cert = os.path.join(lxc_conf_path, 'client.crt')
key = os.path.join(lxc_conf_path, 'client.key')
certs = (cert, key,)
print('Certs:', certs)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

endpoint = requests_unixsocket.DEFAULT_SCHEME + parse.quote(unix_socket, safe='')
session = requests_unixsocket.Session()

json={
    "command": tuple(shlex('pwd')),
    "environment": None,
    "wait-for-websocket": True,
    "interactive": True,
    "user": None,
    "group": None,
    "cwd": None,
}

response = session.post(f'{endpoint}/1.0/instances/{instance_name}/exec', json=json)

print('URI:', response.request.method, response.request.url)
if isinstance(response.request.body, bytes):
    print('BODY:', response.request.body.decode('utf-8'))

metadata = response.json()['metadata']
operation_id = metadata['id']
fds = metadata['metadata']['fds']['0']
fds_ctrl = metadata['metadata']['fds']['control']

print(f'{operation_id=}')
print(f'{fds=}')
print(f'{fds_ctrl=}')

uri = f'wss://127.0.0.1:8443/1.0/operations/{operation_id}/websocket?secret={fds}'
uri_ctrl = f'wss://127.0.0.1:8443/1.0/operations/{operation_id}/websocket?secret={fds_ctrl}'
print(uri)
print(uri_ctrl)
```

Output:

```bash
Certs: ('/home/dv/.config/lxc/client.crt', '/home/dv/.config/lxc/client.key')
URI: POST http+unix://%2Fvar%2Flib%2Flxd%2Funix.socket/1.0/instances/pgsql/exec
BODY: {"command": ["pwd"], "environment": null, "wait-for-websocket": true, "interactive": true, "user": null, "group": null, "cwd": null}
operation_id='f53f3e3e-9ddf-479c-907b-11c8ed25b50a'
fds='ea29b9358cb351ad6c58a25e22544e77f763c1052734c9797e32b8e28417b018'
fds_ctrl='4d682de4ef151ab30ceca788009ff46efd563a96efdf93769b3915a843ebc4b0'
wss://127.0.0.1:8443/1.0/operations/f53f3e3e-9ddf-479c-907b-11c8ed25b50a/websocket?secret=ea29b9358cb351ad6c58a25e22544e77f763c1052734c9797e32b8e28417b018
wss://127.0.0.1:8443/1.0/operations/f53f3e3e-9ddf-479c-907b-11c8ed25b50a/websocket?secret=4d682de4ef151ab30ceca788009ff46efd563a96efdf93769b3915a843ebc4b0
```

I got two URL (URI) which are shown in the console output above to connect websokets by documentation [/1.0/operations/{id}/websocket](https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/api/#/operations/operation_websocket_get) or need to use untrusted API link? [/1.0/operations/{id}/websocket?public](https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/api/#/operations/operation_websocket_get_untrusted)

What to do next? How to access a socket and get stdout, stderr, stdin from running a command?

I tried to get to access with [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but server reject all connection by timeout and I don't get anything.

Next example for websokets, for addition to the python code above:

```py
import asyncio
# from websockets.sync.client import ClientConnection, connect, unix_connect
import websockets
import ssl


ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
ssl_context.load_default_certs()
ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certs[0], keyfile=certs[1])
ssl_context.check_hostname = False
ssl_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE


async def message():
    async with websockets.connect(uri=uri, ssl=ssl_context) as socket:
        # msg = input("Write your message to the server: ")
        await socket.send('msg')
        print(await socket.recv())

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(message())
```

Before running a code above, I switched LXD to mode listening on 127.0.0.1:8443:

```
lxc config set core.https_address 127.0.0.1:8443
```

And I get an error after running the code:

```
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: no close frame received or sent
```

I do not know what to do next... Please help

Comment: Well, you aren't going to get stdin, stdout, and stderr.  It's just a pair of sockets.  You can certainly run a command using `subprocess` and use plumbing to route the stdin/stdout to the web sockets.